# $f(a)=g(a)$, $f'(a)=g'(a)$ and $f(x) \leq g(x)$, for all $x \in I$ then $f''(a) \leq g''(a)$

Tags: real-analysis

First of all, f is two times differentiable in the point a.

My first idea was to make the function $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)$ and use the Taylor Formula to get $f''(a) \leq g''(a)$ but for that I would need $f$ to be three times diffentiable at a interval around $a$ and that $f'''(x) \leq g'''(x)$ for all x in  that inverval.

I tried to use another lemma that said that if $f(a) \leq g(a)$, $f'(x) \leq g'(x)$ if $x > a$ implies $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x>a$ but that went nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $a$.

Let $h=g-f$. You know $h(a)=h'(a)=0$, thus $h(x) = \frac{(x-a)^2}{2}h''(a) + o((x-a)^2)$.

If $h''(a) =0$ there's nothing to prove. Otherwise, notice $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{h(x)}{\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}h''(a) }=1$$

Thus $h$ and $\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}h''(a) $ must have the same sign on a neighborhood of $a$. By assumption, $h\geq 0$, thus $h''(a)\geq 0$.

Comment: Question: Why does $o$ is applied in $(x-a)^2$ and not in just $x-a$, does this change the outcome of the proof?

Comment: Why $(x-a)^2$ instead of $x-a$ ? That's Taylor's theorem at order $2$ with Peano form of the remainder. You could apply the same theorem at order $1$ but that wouldn't be enough to deal with your problem.